# Check if there are values other than a certain value exists in a list

Tags: list, python-3.x

I want to check if there is at least one value in a list that is not zero. If there is a value that isn't zero, return true; if not, return false.

For example, if I have a list `[0, 1, 2]`, that would return true because a value other than 0 exists. A list `[0, 0, 0]` would return false because there are only zeroes.

I tried `if not 0 in [0, 1, 2]`, but that does't work because zeroes are allowed. If the list is `[0, 1, 2]`, I could iterate through `[1, 2]` and see if any of those values exist, but that feels very inefficient to me; also, I want it to be dynamic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [`any`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any), it is designed exactly for what you want:

```
In [1]: l =  [0, 1, 2]
In [2]: any(l)
Out[2]: True
In [4]: l =  []
In [5]: any(l)
Out[5]: False    
In [6]: l =  [0,0,0]    
In [7]: any(l)
Out[7]: False
```

If any value is non-zero it will short circuit and return True, if it gets to the end of the list or you pass an empty list it will return False.

So in your code:

```
if any(some_list):
   # found at least one non-zero
else:
   # empty or all zero
```

If you wanted to check that there was a number greater 1 you would add some logic in the expression:

```
if any(i > 1 for i in some_list)
```

The implementation logic is in the linked docs:

```
def any(iterable):
    for element in iterable:
        if element:
            return True
    return False
```

One thing to be aware of is *any* will return True for  any *truthy* value like a non-empty list, tuple, True etc.. and False for any *falsey* values like an empty list, tuple, False etc.. so in certain cases you would need to explicitly check.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You may want to know how `any` works. Something like this:

```
def check_list(nums):
    for n in nums:
        if n:   # check if the number is not zero
            return True   # immediately return True
    return False   # reached the end of the list already but no luck, so return False

check_list([0,1,2]) == True
check_list([0,0,0]) == False
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a simple solution using count

```
def has_other(data, value):
    return data.count(value) != len(data)

a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [0, 0, 0]

print(has_other(a, 0)) # True
print(has_other(b, 0)) # False
```